# Accessing GPIO pins of ESP8266-01

Tags: esp8266

I have a couple 8Pin ESP-01 Modules with an ESP8266. I am planning to use them to read a DHT22 sensor with them and sent the information further via MQTT. On the developer board this works perfectly with the SDA pin D2. However, on my 8Pin ESP-01 a don't get any information.

The 8 Pins are labeled:

| 1. Row | 2. Row |
| --- | --- |
| 3V3 | RX |
| RST | IOa (I think its an "a") |
| EN | IO2 |
| TX | GND |

In order to confirm that I address the correct pin I thought I test the pin with a blinking LED and test all pins from 1-18 (see code below). However, no matter which Pin I checked the LED never blinked.

```
void setup() 
{ 
pinMode(#, OUTPUT); 
} 

void loop()
{ 
digitalWrite(#, HIGH);
delay(1000); 
digitalWrite(#, LOW); 
delay(1000); 
}
```

The questions are:

- Do I need to use the SDA pin?
- How to define this pin on the ESP-01 board?

Comment: I don't have the hardware to investigate, but does [How to Use ESP-01 ESP-01S Pins and Leds](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-use-the-ESP8266-01-pins/) help on how to use the pins?

Comment: thx, this helped alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference:

It turns out my ESP did not boot correctly (If only the red LED lights up, without any flicker of the blue LED, there is a problem).

In order to achieve that I needed to pull-up the CH_PD (EN) and IO0 (IOa) pin using two 10KOhm resistors.

Comment: kEKs - Hi, Thanks for coming back with the solution. Please consider áccepting this self-answer to effectively mark the topic as solved, which you can do 48 hours after you asked the question (i.e. after 14.44Z today - that system-imposed delay is to allow other people a chance to provide answers). TY